# How to update reactivevar dependent on a framerate?

Tags: meteor

I have problems understanding how exactly meteor's `ReactiveVar` works. What i think i should do :

```
Template.template_canvas.onCreated(function() {
  this.config = new ReactiveVar([{
    name: 'FPS',
    value: Engine.mFPS
  }, {
    name: 'ElapsedTime',
    value: Engine.mElapsedTime
  }, {
    name: 'LagTime',
    value: Engine.mLagTime
  }, {
    name: 'PreviousTime',
    value: Engine.mPreviousTime
  }]);

});

Template.template_canvas.helpers({
  displayConfigs: function() {
    return Template.instance().config.get();
  }
});
```

ALL `Engine` variables are updated every `40ms`.
And when i try to display them :

```
<template name="template_canvas">
    <div id='info_log' draggable="true" >
        <ul>
            {{#each displayConfigs}}
            <li> {{name}}  {{value}} </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <canvas id='canvas_app'></canvas>
</template>
```

ONLY the default variables of `Engine` are displayed.
[image]
Which means the variables arent changing at all.
However they are changing according to console.log !

EDIT :

```
export default class Engine {
  static start(application) {
    Engine.Application = application;
    Engine.mPreviousTime = Date.now();
    Engine.mLagTime = 0.0;
    Engine.mIsRunning = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      Engine.run.call(Engine.Application);
    });
  }

  static run() {
    if (Engine.mIsRunning) {
      requestAnimationFrame(
        function() {
          Engine.run.call(Engine.Application);
        }
      );
      Engine.mCurrentTime = Date.now();
      Engine.mElapsedTime = Engine.mCurrentTime - Engine.mPreviousTime;
      Engine.mPreviousTime = Engine.mCurrentTime;
      Engine.mLagTime += Engine.mElapsedTime;

      // LagTime is the sum of the elapsed Time based on the last Frame.
      // So if the time passed is bigger than the given time, which bigger than milliseconds per frame
      // then we have to update.
      while ((Engine.mLagTime >= Engine.mMPF) && Engine.mIsRunning) {
        this.update();
        Engine.mLagTime -= Engine.mMPF;
      }

      // Should be called every 25ms, since we have 25ms per Frame.
      //
      this.draw();

    }
  }

}
// Frames per second.
//
Engine.mFPS = 40;

// Milliseconds per Frame 25ms/Frame with 40 FPS
Engine.mMPF = 1000 / Engine.mFPS;
Engine.mPreviousTime = 0;
Engine.mLagTime = 0;
Engine.mCurrentTime = 0;
Engine.mElapsedTime = 0;

Engine.mIsRunning = false;
Engine.Application = null;
```

Comment: Are you needing to update the entire array each time one object changes, or just that object? Also, can you show `Engine` definition?

Comment: @Jeremiah It depends, FPS should be the same, but yes i want to update the entire array. See my edit.

Comment: @Jeremiah what i am missing here is something like a global "listener", where i can update the array dependent on my framerate...

Comment: There is a package called reactive dict that might suit your needs.

Comment: Tracker#Dependency looks promising: https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency. Here's a tutorial: http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-reactive-data-types/ In the "Roll your own" sub-heading.

Comment: @Jeremiah great article, i will give it a try